Allow every new AirPort network password access for my application
I made a CLI wifi that generates a QR-Code of the current wifi to connect with other devices. This CLI uses the next command:
security find-generic-password -a "$NETWORK" -D 'AirPort network password' -w

I would like this command not to prompt for user and password every time. But either not need for any authorisation (I know this may compromise the passwords, but I'm ok compromising passwords of wifi networks for whom have local access to my laptop). Or an authorisation using Touch Id (like sudo).
I found that I can change Access Control per password per application, but I would like to be able to do this with every new WiFi password I connect to, automatically.
